# How can i calculate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(1^n+2^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$?

Tags: limits

How can i calculate it?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(1^n+2^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

I don't have idea how to do it..

Comment: Hint: $5^n$ grows much faster than the other exponentials so that you essentially have $(5^n)^{1/n}$.

Comment: That is extremely dangerous hint to give. In $(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ the fraction obviously tends to zero too, but the limit is not 1. You cannot generally discard stuff when it is part of inner function.

Comment: @Ordoshsen $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\mathcal O(1/n^x))^n$ for any $x>1$, and exponential functions are $\mathcal O(1/n^x)$.

Answer (score 12):

*Hint:* $5^n \le 1^n+2^n+5^n \le 3 \cdot 5^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$L = \lim_{n\to \infty}{(1^n+2^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

$$\ln L = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln (1^n+2^n+5^n)}{n}  \\ 
=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{2^n\ln2+5^n\ln5}{1^n+2^n+5^n}}{1}
=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{2^n\ln2}{1^n+2^n+5^n}+\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{5^n\ln5}{1^n+2^n+5^n}\\
=0 + \ln 5$$

$$L =5$$

Answer (score 1):

**Another Hint:**
$$
\left(1^n+2^n+5^n\right)^{1/n}=5\left(\left(\frac15\right)^n+\left(\frac25\right)^n+1\right)^{1/n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{(1^n+2^n+5^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}} =5\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{5^n}+\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^n+1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} = 5$$